# Java Virtual Objects

Tags: java

I am in a situation where I cannot use reflection at all. Needless to say, I also need to dynamically create classes. As there something already created out there that allows you to create virtual java objects. Just off of the top of my head, a java virtual object would be ... say a map of Strings to objects, where the Strings are names, and the objects are the objects themselves. Of course you could add all kinds of meta-data in there, like another map that contains privacy, etc. Does something like this exist? Also, instead of doing the way I described above (using maps, etc) what about if I created a class in binary form?

Comment: Why can't you just do what you wrote?

Comment: Why can't you use reflection?  Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: because of constraints with the environment. I am using a JNLP file with the all-permissions not set. No this is not homework. My co-worker implemented a work around but via ant. I just wondered if something like this could have been addressed without the need to edit the build script.

"Why can't you just do what you wrote?" I can, I just wanted some feedback from others on the idea. If it has already been done, no point in doing from scratch.

Comment: Perhaps you could use a Proxy.  Though I would guess for this purpose that would count as using reflection.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to compile a class on the fly from source using the compiler API, though I have never done it.  See the javax.tools package.

It's also possible to load a class from a byte array of class data.  See java.lang ClassLoader.

But why not just do as you suggest and have a `Map<String,Object>`?

Comment: I was thinking about it, but wanted to first hear what others thought. I am debating which way I should go .. should I use the Map approach, or build a class using byte code and then handing off a reference to it. I think the map way might be the better way to go, I could include other meta-data such as privacy, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using a [Dynabean](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/LazyDynaBean.html) from apache commons beanutils.

Not sure how much value it would provide over just a normal map.